# What is the best way to build unique CSS locators for Selenide+Java?

Tags: java, css-selectors, selenide

Often happens when locator is valid in console panel but after running test Selenide still doesn't find the needed element. How to check whether the locator is right?

Answer (score 1):

I normally put a debug point on the element and see if the element can be found. Alternatively if you don't want to debug, I put a sleep of 2sec before the element, just to tests. 
If the element is then visible, I know that I can put a waitUntil on that element and it will work.